# How do I extract and decode an ASN.1 message on tvOS?

Tags: app-store, tvos, apple-tv, security-framework

I would like to extract some information from the App Store receipt in a tvOS app. I thought I could use the Security framework, but the following two header files are missing:

```
#import <Security/SecAsn1Types.h>
#import <Security/SecAsn1Templates.h>
```

In the OS X SDK these header files exist. Was ASN.1 support removed from the public tvOS SDK? Do I have to use OpenSSL to handle the receipt?

Answer (score 1):

Security Framework is not included in Apple tvOS framework hence you cannot see this library and imports.

Please follow this link for more clarification about listing of frameworks.

[Apple frameworks listing](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/releasenotes/General/tvOS90APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016577)

Also for the discussion forum guys already mentioned that in case you need to use the secure storage you can only do it using and CloudKit framework only.

[Discussion forum for apple local storage issue](https://dzone.com/articles/local-storage-on-the-new-apple-tv)